# Not sure how to use a tkinter entry to run an if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have an Entry set up and I would like to run and if-statement if the entry is `==` the environment variable I have set up. I already have a button set up to print the input but I am unsure of how to use the input in an if-statement.

```
import os
import base64
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()


passwordinput = Entry(master, text ="Password")
passwordinput.pack()

def outputentry():
    input = passwordinput.get()
    print (input)

printpassword = Button(master, text="Print", command = outputentry)
printpassword.pack()

password = os.environ.get('USERPASS')

if input == password:
    print("Welcome")
    os.startfile('E:\Documents')
else:
        print("Incorrect password")  

master.mainloop()
```

I would like to enter the correct password which is defined in my environment variables and then run the if-statement if the passwords match.

Comment: You need to do the comparison inside of `outputentry()`.  Where you have it now, it's being executed immediately after the Entry and Button were created, long before the user has had a chance to type anything in.

Comment: Have you tried `os.getenv('USERPASS')`, rather than `os.environ.get('USERPASS')`?

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper that was it, I have gotten it working now thank you.